# How to wrap an existing memory buffer as a DC in native win32?

Tags: image, winapi, memory, draw, gdi

I have an image in memory defined of an array 32bit ARGB values. I'ld like to get a DC of that to draw on it and afterwards have the result in the same array. The image never gets displayed on the screen by blitting.

Is this possible without copying the image data around?

When I look at the CreateDC() page of msdn, it needs a driver name and a device. But the dc doesn't have to be compatible to any device. Besides, I don't want the result to be different if the display runs in 16 bits or 32 bits color depth. I think I need a DC compatible to my memory layout, not compatible to some device. How can I do that?

Thx
   Marc

Comment: This is covered well by `<gdiplus.h>`.  Create the bitmap with the Bitmap(int, int, int, PixelFormat, BYTE*) constructor.  Draw with the Graphics object you get from Graphics::FromImage().

Answer (score 3):

The `CreateDIBSection` lets you specify where the memory for the bitmap is stored. It needs to be in a memory-mapped section, however.

Comment: What is a memory-mapped section? Also, as per my comments on David's answer, can `CreateDIBSection` be used to get a HBITMAP handle to the existing memory buffer, or does it copy the data to a new memory location?

Comment: CreateFileMapping creates memory-mapped sections. You can pass the section to CreateDIBSection and it will use that memory (by reference, not a copy).

Comment: Thanks. I'd come across a similar suggestion elsewhere, but I find the `CreateFileMapping` documentation very hard to understand - it seems to expect a filename but data is in memory, not in a file. How do I use the function without a file?

Comment: Like it says in the docs, pass `INVALID_FILE_HANDLE` if you want a file-less mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a bitmap and [select that bitmap into your DC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  The bitmap is created using your memory buffer.

Ue either [`CreateBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (device-dependent) or [`CreateDIBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (device-independent; this is what I'd recommend, especially since you don't want it affected by the display colour depth - that means it should be device-independent.)  Both have parameters to point at an existing memory buffer.  For `CreateDIBitmap`, for example, you need to pass the `CBM_INIT` flag and then pass a pointer to your buffer as the `lpbInit` parameter.  You will also need to pass in a `BITMAPINFO` structure that describes the format of the bitmap.

CreateBitmap lets you do the same thing, in slightly simpler fashion, but the bitmap (being device-dependent) is not as flexible to use.

(You may want to use [CreateCompatibleDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922550.aspx) over CreateDC, by the way - depends, but it's often what you're after.)

For more information on using DCs and bitmaps, read something like [this article](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html).  (I'm not sure from your question how familiar you are with them or general GDI programming.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, CreateDIBitmap will copy the bitmap data from your memory buffer into newly allocated memory, and return a HBITMAP handle to the copy. I, like the OP, am looking for a way to get a DC which draws directly onto the existing memory buffer rather than a copy of it. Any ideas?